# Angularjs event when page is fully compiled?

Tags: angularjs

I need to fire a function call when all directives in the document are fully rendered and compiled.
The call has to be outside of all directives, as it has to do with all the directives' scopes.

Some code:

```
<body *here I want an event such as onload(someFunc) that happens after angular's rendering,not only html's*>
<directive1>
<directiv1.1></directive1.1>
</directive1>    
<directive2></directive2>
</body>
```

Is there any way to catch such an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try using the `$viewContentLoaded` event

> Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.

As per the documentation: [See doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Another interesting article on this: [Article](http://aleaiactaest.ch/2012/06/28/angular-js-and-dom-readyness-for-jquery/)